# Fixed positioned element scrolls with page until the scrolling is complete in Firefox mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have an element, which CSS is `position: fixed`.

It works fine on PC browsers, but it works badly on mobile browsers (especially Firefox)

The problem is that the fixed positioned element scrolls with the page and then awkwardly snap back into position once scrolling is complete.

Here's the demonstration: (Notice the “Top” block at the bottom right corner, which is a fixed positioned element)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zod73.jpg

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mobile browsers, "fixed" is discussed at length here:
http://bradfrost.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/

You could use jQuery Mobile, as discussed here:
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html

You'd end up with something like

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
  <h1>Fixed Header!</h1>
</div>
```